# Customize Flutter service worker

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Flutter automatically generates a service worker `flutter_service_worker.js` when building for the web but I would like to add my own fetch/caching rules for third-party routes.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the only workaround that I have found is to make a script that post-processes the generated `flutter_service_worker.js` and replaces:

```
  if (!RESOURCES[key]) {
    return;
  }
```

by

```
  if (!RESOURCES[key]) {
     return customFetch();
  }
```

where `customFetch()` implements my own caching rules.

Comment: Should be of some interest to keep an eye on this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67625